# How do I improve my approach towards this feature selection and model building for large multiclass dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I know this is technically assignment question.

The training data contains 9000 observations and 900 features. I have to build the model to predict the testing data, which contains roughly 5,000 observations and same number of features as the training data.

I am wondering that since there are so many features, we use PCA for feature selection? I tried random forest, lasso regression, but they are so slow. I am not hitting the good accuracy using the features given by PCA.

Should I use random samples for random forest or lasso regression?

For modeling, I notice that SVM overperforms compared to naive bayes, neural network, and linear discrimnant analysis. Should I just use SVM over the ensemble method, because of multiclass data? I am getting roughly 88 percent correct on hold one leave one out of training data, but 25 percent correct on testing data.

For the binary data, I was able to get good accuracy(not perfect) by lasso for feature selection and doing ensemble method of logistic regression, neural network, svm, qda, and lda.